# Can't reference capture group in Notepad++ regex search and replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using Notepad++ v6.5.5

I have the following regex:

```
((?<=,)[,\ \/\-#\w]{2,}(?=,[0-9]))
```

I'm trying to capture the text `Dow Corning / Molykote 111,  Valve Lubricant` in the following row:

```
111,Dow Corning / Molykote 111,  Valve Lubricant,25.000000,Y,46.010000,1,1 MSRP
```

It captures just fine, but I can't seem to reference the replace group.

I've tried the following:

```
"$0"
"$1"
"$2"
"$3"
"\0"
"\1"
"\2"
"\3"
\1 = "\1"
```

And I've also moved the parentheses to inside of the lookahead and lookbehind:

```
(?<=,)([,\ \/\-#\w]{2,})(?=,[0-9])
```

I attempted to replace the text with the following gibberish:

```
ansfnasflknsf
```

Nothing is being replaced.  Not sure what's going on, really.  I can use find/replace just fine with plain text, but not regex.

---

Gah, just tried v6.4.5 and it still didn't work.

If someone gets this to work, can they let me know what version they're using?

---

The following regex is a little better for capturing what I need:

`((?<=,)(?<!\ )[,\ \/\-#\w]{2,}(?=,[0-9\.]+))`

Comment: and what do you want to obtain after the replacement?

Comment: What version of notepad++ are you using? Are you even getting a match when using only Find?

Comment: I just want to surround it with quotes.  But it's not replacing anything when I use regex.  I'm using version 6.5.5.  Yes, I get a match when using only find.

Comment: Lookaheads and lookbehinds are non-capturing constructs. The groups inside them do capture things, but they do not correspond to any text in the input, because they are zero-length.

Comment: is it always fields 2 and 3 on each lines?

Comment: The group I'm trying to capture is a whole field, but there might be commas inside.

Comment: Well, [it's working fine on my 6.5.2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lweOJ.png). Can't reproduce your problem with your supplied line. Make sure your cursor is at the start and you are finding 'down'.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'd like to capture the group inside of the lookahead and lookbehind.

Comment: @Zaemz Ah, OK, this makes sense. I'm surprised that it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

Just `$1` will work. `$0` references the whole original string. (My N++ version is 6.6.9.)

Answer (score 1):

With a reasonable recent version of notepad++ you can do that:

```
find:    ^[^,]*,\K.+?(?=,[0-9.]+,)
replace: "$0"
```

Comment: If I remove the first caret the regex works, but unfortunately the replacement isn't working.  I'm going to try a different version of notepad++.

Comment: @Zaemz: It seems to be a bug in npp, to avoid the problem, you can put the cursor at the begining of the document and click replaceAll button.